# I would like to learn to turn on my phone flashlight from Gnu/Linux

Tags: kali-linux

I want to be able to turn on my phones flashlight from Kali Linux, but when I look for anything about it there is nothing on this subject.
Does anyone have experience on the subject?

Comment: This question lacks detail to give a good answer. You say nothing about your experience. You probably won't find a tutorial on how to write a program to remotely switch on the flash light of my phone from kali linux. You need to break down the problem.

Comment: Shows no effort, downvote

Comment: The question would be better served at https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions However we would need to know more about you. Please improve the question, then we can move it, and **up-vote** it.

Comment: It depends. How are you connected to your phone from your Kali Linux desktop? Or were you already able to install Kali on your phone?

Comment: @AdminBee. I just checked. It was a duplicate by the same user. The community deleted it. (delete this comment when read, and also yours)

Answer (score 2):

First don't use kali-linux. It is a security tool, for use by experts.
Use Debian Gnu/Linux. It is good for developing and general use.

This looks like a good learning project. If you are a complete noob, then it will take a long time. Don't rush, to the end, there is a lot to learn on the way. (If you were to remove **some** of the learning steps, it is what I (an experience software developer) would do.)

An order that you could learn is:

- Install Debian Gnu/Linux.
- Learn a programming language: Berkeley-snap, then python, then ...
- Write a program that turns on/off a picture of a light.
- Learn about android development (depending on phone OS).
- Write a program, on phone, that turns the light on and off (on a timer).
- Learn about network communication.
- Split the program on the PC, to be a controller and controlled.
- Move the controlled onto the phone.
- Learn how to do network communication securely.